# Rewrite TeX in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tex

1. How hard is it to rewrite Knuth's [TeX algorithm](http://brokestream.com/tex.pdf) in Haskell?
2. Is anyone aware of any efforts along these lines? (I know of [HaTeX](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HaTeX) - but it compiles *to* LaTeX)

Comment: First part of this question is impossible to answer. (Or: the answer is "it depends")

Comment: I don't see why you would want to. Haskell's a great language to program in, but TeX is a very mature, stable tool that does its job very well. What benefit would come of it?

Comment: @AndrewC: I think the point is that TeX syntax, while nicely concise for many applications, is also often unwieldy, so it would be nice to be able to write some parts directly in Haskell. And, especially from a Haskell POV, TeX is very unsafe since the entire parsing is only decided while processing a file. That's what IMO prevents HaTeX from being really useful: there, LaTeX code is a monoid, but that doesn't quite work out since the same piece of code can in principle have completely different meanings, so HaTeX can't really do much with the code. On the other hand, a full interpreter could.